Different rendering when creating QWidget from class or method
I'm building a GUI with Pyside 6, especially a title bar at the top. Seeing that I have many widgets, I've created a class to extend QWidget and set ContentsMargins and Spacing to 0 by default. Here's an example with QHBoxLayout:
class HBox(QWidget):

    def __init__(self, no_margins=True, no_spacing=True):

        super().__init__()
        
        layout = QHBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(layout)
        
        if no_margins:
            layout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
            
        if no_spacing:
            layout.setSpacing(0)

However, the title bar gets a greyish background instead of the dark blue one inherited from the central widget:

I was able to overcome the issue by embedding the code in a method instead:
def HBox(no_margins=True, no_spacing=True):

    widget = QWidget()
    layout = QHBoxLayout()
    widget.setLayout(layout)

    if no_margins:
        layout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)

    if no_spacing:
        layout.setSpacing(0)

    return widget

With the method, the rendering is actually correct:

For context, the title bar widget is created like this either way:
central_widget = Grid()
central_widget.setAutoFillBackground(True)
central_widget.setStyleSheet(f"background-color: {colors['ui_background_first']};")

title_bar = HBox()
title_bar.setFixedHeight(20)
title_bar.layout().setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)

[...]

central_widget.layout().addWidget(title_bar)

As you can guess, Grid() works the same way as HBox(). Although the method works, I find the class more elegant, but can't spot the difference causing the rendering issue. Any ideas?

From the QSS reference about styling QWidget: "If you subclass from QWidget, you need to provide a paintEvent for your custom QWidget". Alternatively, set the Qt.WA_StyledBackground attribute. Note: you should avoid generic QSS properties in container widgets, as they're arbitrarily applied to all children (which can cause unexpected results in complex widgets); always prefer selector types instead.
